# How to copy file and replace numbers to X?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I have file in home/files/file.txt

and its contents mixed with letter and numbers

```
SDA212 
123DD2
31dD
```

I want to copy file into other directory and at the same time replace numeric values with just X letter? I there any way that how I can do this?

Comment: Yes sure, but what have you tried so far

Comment: I've tried sed, but I was unable to set change command (numbers to letter x)

Comment: @deuq : (1) You forgot to post your own attempt to solve the problem. (2) You forgot to explain what you mean by _numeric values_: Every single digit? Every line consisting solely of digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `sed`.

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]/X/g' /home/files/file.txt > /path/somewhere/else.txt
```

Result:

```
SDAXXX 
XXXDDX
XXdD
```

**Edit**: As @Ted Lyngmo pointed out, depending on your version of `sed`, you may be able to use the `\d` escape for digits:

```
sed -e 's/\d/X/g' /home/files/file.txt > /path/somewhere/else.txt
```

Just be aware that this is a gnu extension and may not be available on all systems.

Comment: No good reason @TedLyngmo just force of habit and a rushed answer. I'll edit the post

Comment: `sed -E 's/\d/X/g'` would be an option unless POSIX is required

Comment: I do like the `\d` in general, much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `tr` program. I think something like `tr '[:digit:]' X` would work.

Comment: I wonder why you don't get more upvotes? Could it be for the pointless mentioning of making a short C program? `tr [:digit:] X` is excellent as it is (which is why I upvoted your answer too).

Comment: @Ted you could have edited that part out. Once an answer is posted, it belongs to the community, not its author.

Comment: @oguzismail You are right and I sometimes do and sometimes don't.  In this case I made the comment to encourage the poster to make the change - but I admit that I also did it to draw attention to the answer. Perhaps not in the best way possible. I made my contribution now instead :-)